# remove duplicate rows based on substring match

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql column nvarchar(200) which has the following values

```
    xxx {"Name":"Stack"} yyy
    aaa {"Name":"Overflow"} bbb
    ccc {"Name":Stack"} ddd
    eee {"Name":"Overflow"} fff
```

I want to remove the first duplicate row where the Name is the same i.e in the example above I would want to remove the 3 and 4 row because it contains a duplicate name but I want to keep the first row and the second row.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is this data exactly valid, do you expect to match `"Name":"Stack"` and `"Name":Stack"` with the typo as being the same?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the part you are interested in is delimited by "{" and "}" and that you have an id to establish the ordering (that is define what is first), then you can do this with a relatively direct query.

The innermost subquery finds the "name" definition.  The next level assigns a sequential number to each on using `row_number()` and the outermost selects the first one:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by NamePortion order by id) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   substring(t.col,
                             charindex('{', t.col),
                             charindex('}', t.col) - charindex('{', t.col)
                            ) as NamePortion
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I forgot to mention the tricky part and that is the ending } does not guarantee that it just contains "Name":"x". The value can be {xxx,yyy}{"Name":"x", "age":10} and the second row can be like {x}{"Name":"x"}